# error: ‘POPT_ARG_ARGV’ undeclared. Do I need to use an older gcc?

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to build a C++ project from [https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.)

However, when I run the command

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

This error appeared,

```
error: ‘POPT_ARG_ARGV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Not sure if it's relevent, but my GCC

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
```

My CentOS

```
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS 5.x has popt version 1.13, but the POPT_ARG_ARGV type was added in version 1.14.

Comment: Getting the same on CentOS 7, although compiler and OS is much newer that v5 - gcc 7.3.1 from devtoolset-7.

Comment: CentOS 7 also has popt 1.13 and that doesn't change with devtoolset-7.